# A novel where a woman from "future" of 1999 speaks leet-speak

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm trying to remember the name of a novel/series I read back in the mid-eighties.  I can't remember the author other than that it was a known older author.  I initially thought maybe Saberhagen or Harrison, but can't find it in their bibliographies.

It involved a collection of 4-5 people from different times/places.  The distinctive bit I can remember was that one of them (not the main character) was a cyberpunkish woman from the "future" of 1999 who spoke in futuristic dialect of English that the other characters, including the protagonist, from the "present" (from the eighties) could not understand.

Unfortunately, I don't remember much else of the plot other than that they were making their way through ruins.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you're referring to [Philip Jose Farmer's "The Dungeon Series](http://www.fantasticfiction.co.uk/series/philip-jose-farmers-the-dungeon/)- a collection of six books [written by various authors under PJF's name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeon_series). This steampunk-ish story revolves around Clive Folliot's search for his twin brother. During the search, he ends up in a different world, and meets up with Annie (a descendant from the future who speaks in a strange dialect- we'd call it leetspeak), Shriek, a spider-like creature, a twisted dwarf-like creature and many others.

Comment: That's it!  Thanks!